# Listen not working with sass-3.3.0.rc.3 - Undfined Method

Tags: ruby, sass, compass-sass

Decided I wanted to update my sass development environment today to use source maps and I seem stuck on this error. I've tried moving to a new version of ruby by switching to rbenv, uninstalled everything, reinstalled everything. Even went and made sure there were no stray references to the old listen in the mac install of ruby. I can't seem to get past this. this is the trace on the watch.

```
 sass --watch scss:public/css --trace 
 >>> Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.

 ~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.3/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:306:in `create_listener': undefined method `to' for Listen:Module (NoMethodError)
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.3/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:233:in `watch'
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.3/lib/sass/plugin.rb:108:in `method_missing'
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.3/lib/sass/exec.rb:509:in `watch_or_update'
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.3/lib/sass/exec.rb:346:in `process_result'
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.3/lib/sass/exec.rb:43:in `parse'
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.3/lib/sass/exec.rb:22:in `parse!'
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.3/bin/sass:13:in `<top (required)>'
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/bin/sass:23:in `load'
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/bin/sass:23:in `<main>'
```

Showing which version of ruby is being used:

```
     [scott] ~/CODE/ $ which ruby
     ~/.rbenv/shims/ruby
```

here's the gem list output

```
     bigdecimal (1.2.5, 1.2.3)
     bundler (1.5.3)
     celluloid (0.15.2)
     chunky_png (1.2.9)
     ffi (1.9.3)
     fssm (0.2.10)
     hitimes (1.2.1)
     io-console (0.4.2)
     json (1.8.1)
     listen (2.4.1)
     minitest (5.2.2, 4.7.5)
     multi_json (1.8.4)
     psych (2.0.4, 2.0.2)
     rake (10.1.1, 10.1.0)
     rb-fsevent (0.9.4)
     rb-inotify (0.9.3)
     rb-kqueue (0.2.0)
     rdoc (4.1.1, 4.1.0)
     rubygems-update (2.2.2)
     sass (3.3.0.rc.3)
     test-unit (2.5.5, 2.1.0.0)
     timers (2.0.0, 1.1.0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same issue here.

Using older version solves the problem so

```
$ gem uninstall sass
$ gem install sass -v 3.3.0.rc.2
```

And don't forget proper compass version

```
$gem install compass -v 0.13.alpha.12
```